# Enum Pairing and Searching C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, search, enums

I am trying to pair an Enum to another. I have an Enum that has 35 different emote names like "angry","sad","happy"... The enum values are in a dropdown and I can search through them. So I want to create another enum that has values for the first enum like "smile" is ":)", "laugh" is ":D". So when I type ":D" in searchbar I want it to give me the laugh option in dropdown.

Comment: how about `Dictionary<Emote,string>{{Emote.smile,☺️)},{Emote.laugh,}} `

Comment: But I have 35 options in the enum so do I have to this one by one ?

Comment: sure, there has to be a mapping metween the enum and the smiley

Comment: You'll need to enter the information somewhere and as @fubo points out a Dictionary type is made for this.

Comment: So do I need to create another enum for ": )" this type of emotes and pair them with the equivalent names in the other enum

Comment: afaik in general enums can only have numeric underlying values .. no strings

Comment: could you show some definitions of some enum and emote? i am curious...  https://github.com/anton-bot/Full-Emoji-List/blob/master/Emoji.cs

Comment: I solved the problem thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0)

Something like

```
var output 
    = names.Zip( // zip names
            emotes, // with the emotes
            (first, second) => new {first, second}) // create a two element object
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.first, kv=> kv.second ); // turn that into a dictionary key-value pair
```

This will create a dictionary where you can use the emoji as a key and it'll return your word, or you can swap round the `names` and `emotes` for the oposite key-value.